# Powershell "ResumeState" what it does

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have trouble understanding piece of PowerShell script I am working with:

```
import-module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure AD Sync\Bin\ADSync\Microsoft.IdentityManagement.PowerShell.Cmdlet.dll"

$connector = "\\SERVERNAME\root\MicrosoftIdentityIntegrationServer:MIIS_ManagementAgent.Name=\"contoso.com\""
$profile = "full import"
$resumeStatus = $connector.ResumeState($profile)
```

What is the last line? I do not have anywhere `ResumeState` declared and google does not show any results for it to be a keyword or PowerShell function

Comment: The `$connector` variable you posted is a string. Strings don't have a `ResumeState` method. I think you may be missing the `[WMI]` type accelerator. (I would also say you should remove the server name from your post.)

Comment: Why don't you ask whoever wrote it?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: I think you are right that it is WMI type. The servername was mock - I changed it before posting but thanks :) I want to port this to .net and I have no idea how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Guy who wrote it does not work at my company anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to read the WMI moniker string:

```
\\SERVERNAME\root\MicrosoftIdentityIntegrationServer:MIIS_ManagementAgent.Name=\"contoso.com\"
```

This means we are looking in the `root\MicrosoftIdentityIntegrationServer` WMI namespace on `SERVERNAME` for a `MIIS_ManagementAgent` class instance with the name `contoso.com`.

Now that you know the WMI class name (`MIIS_ManagementAgent`), you can search for the documentation that tells you about that class:

https://www.google.com/search?&q=MIIS_ManagementAgent

First result is the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697764.aspx

The documentation lists the methods for the class. Notice that there is no `ResumeState` method listed.

It looks to me, based on this little bit of research, that the code is broken because that class has no such method.

Comment: This is in fact correct answer. There is not `ResumeState` method and I just found out that this code never worked. BTW silly thing ask me to rewrite code that never worked.